# Change speed value depends on the mouse position from the center Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, viewport

I change (screen edge movement) the position of the camera on mouse movement to a specified boundary, I want to reduce the speed of the camera according to the mouse position from the center. make the speed = 0 if the mouse is on the edge, and speed =10 while the mouse is at the center with respect to the in between values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine the mouse position on the screen, I would recomment using `Camera.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition)` in your case. This will give you a `Vector3` with x and y ranging from 0 to 1, where (0,0) is the bottom-left and (1,1) is the top right corner of the screen.
With these coordinates you can determine that your mouse is positioned on the edge if either x or y is 0 or 1.

Next you will have to look at the line that goes through the center ((0.5, 0.5)) and your mouse position, and the closest intersection point with the edges of the screen. With this you can determine the ratio of distance to the edge and to the center and use something like `Mathf.Lerp` to scale your desired camera speed. (You have to determine the edge intersection point, as your screen is not spherical, if that was the case, you could just look at the distance of the mouse positione to the center and the maximum distance).

See: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToViewportPoint.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html